# OpenCV.js is not working vue.js (electron-builder)

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, vue.js, electron

I am working on a project with electron and vuejs (i am using vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) and I require real time face detection system the fastest and most effective solution so far is OpenCV.js (i have done my research).

The problem that i have been facing is according to the OpenCV.js Docs we need to add the script tag to the html file like,

```
<script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady()" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tested it and it works fine only if I turn off nodeIntegration in electron window. But this is not possible because the electron-builder plugin works only if the nodeIntegrations are turned on.

```
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true // I need this but i also need opencv
                              // but opencv is not working if i turn it off.
    }
})
```

Secondly, should I keep using electron or move to NW.js i have noted that the build size of electron.js are huge.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the following statement is not true:

> electron-builder plugin works only if the nodeIntegrations are turned on.

In fact, `nodeIntegration` is going to be disabled in `electron-builder v2.0` by default.

Now let's get to the point. Do not download anything using a `<script>` tag, if you do this, every time a user opens the app, it will download the script. What you should do is to install all the node modules during development, so that everything comes with the app.

To use opencv in Electron, you can simply Install [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs). Check out [the example](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs#usage-with-electron) on how to use it in Electron.

If that module doesn't work for you, try [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv) and follow the opencv [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/de6/tutorial_js_nodejs.html) if needed.

And to answer your question about NW.js, it depends on your needs. Google the differences between Electron and NW.js and decide what you want to use for your app. In short, Electron is more powerful and more secure, even if the app takes up `200mb` more on the drive, it's still a better option. Besides, who cares if the build is `400mb` in size? It's not 2010, nowadays most people who's going to use your app in the first place, most likely have half a terrabyte of free space on their drives.

Comment: Have you integrated OpenCV.js with a web-application. It is a 7mb emscripten file (web-assembly) file it can not be loaded with the web pack or any bundler. and aside from this i have mentioned that i am using vuejs-electron-builder plugin. not the simple electron-builder the vuejs plugin currently required the nodeIntegration to work and do not worry about the downloads. all the files will be bundled with the build. and vuejs is used for SPA's, So, user is never gonna reload the page.

Comment: @ArishKhan mate, you're a bit confused about how it all works, webpack has nothing to do with "loading" modules. I showed you the link to the npm binding module for opencv, just try to install it and use it. I was talking about [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder). I've built 2 Electron apps with that plugin and I know that it doesn't need `nodeIntegration` to work.

Comment: yes i am talking about vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder i just wrote that in short, by loading i meant (it takes foreever to bundle the binary file) bundling. i do not known much about vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder but whenever i turn nodeIntegration off, a message is shown in console saying `require` was not found. but i am gonna try that binding you referred, thanks

Comment: as you said nodeIntegration will be disabled than i will have to use the ipc inter process communcation. it wouldn't be effective since i need to stream the data and interprocess operations will reduce the performace that is why i am avoiding native binding.

Comment: @ArishKhan you are welcome. Yeah I wouldn't disable nodeIntegration as well, since you loose a lot of functionality with it. Also If that binding module I mentioned doesn't work for you, then try [opencv4nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs) module, I think it will be easier to install, they even have examples on how to use it in Electron, here's the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs#usage-with-electron

Comment: a last problem. how do i disable the `require` not found error when i disable nodeIntegration

Comment: @ArishKhan to remove that error you have to remove all `require` in your renderer process, because `require` is Node's method, so when you disable nodeIntegration you simply cannot use `require` in renderer processes. You will have to use `ipc` or import modules using  ES6 `import` method. Also I've update the answer and specified a better module in the previous comment, make sure to check it out, I think that's the module you need.